# What is the recommended way to write then read data in my firebase app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was wondering the best way to write then read data in my firebase app?

I currently make a post request and use `set` to set some data at a new location. the user does this via a modal

I then close the modal and want the user to see the updated content below (without a page refresh) is there anyway to use the completion callback to send back the new data?

should I make an api request again straight after?

or should I handle this client side?

so far I had this:

```
        firebaseApp
            .database()
            .ref(`users/${userID}/${endpoint}`)
            .set(setSchema, (error) => {
                if(error){
                    consolse.log('error')
                } else {
                    console.log('success') 
                }
            })
```

is there anywhere on the success line we can return data?

thanks

Comment: Why not store the data you're setting to a state variable with a state hook (`useState`) that'll trigger a re-render when updated and in turn update the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to use the completion callback to send back the new
>   data?

No, the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set) method does not return the value that is written at the Realtime Database node.

> Should I make an api request again straight after?

It depends, see the next question.

> Or should I handle this client side?

Normally you should be able to handle that in the client since you know what value (Object) you have passed to the `set()` method.

The only case when this is not true is when you use a sentinel (placeholder) value through [`firebase.database.ServerValue`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue).

For example is you have a property `startedAt: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` in the object you pass to the `set()` method, the exact value for `startedAt` will be calculated by the server, therefore you don't know it in advance. If you want to get this value, you need to query the database for it.